# What is the envy of Satan to Adam & Eve that resulted in the entry of death in the Garden of Eden?

Tags: catholicism, genesis, satan, adam-and-eve

> Wisdom 2:23-25 Douay-Rheims 1899 American Edition (DRA)
> 23 For God created man incorruptible, and to the image of his own likeness he made him.
> 24 But by the envy of the devil, death came into the world:
> 25 And they follow him that are of his side

Satan as Lucifer in the heavenly realms is the most beautiful angels created by God with superior knowledge and intellect over the mulititudes of angels.

But, in his pride and disobedience Lucifer was cast down on earth by a lower Archangel St. Michael who rebuked him saying "Who is like unto God".

In the garden, Lucifer cast down is describes in the Book Ezekiel as follows:

> “...You were the seal of perfection,Full of wisdom and perfect in beauty.
>
> You were in Eden, the garden of God;Every precious stone was your covering:
> The sardius, topaz, and diamond,Beryl, onyx, and jasper,Sapphire, turquoise, and emerald with gold.The workmanship of your timbrels and pipes
> Was prepared for you on the day you were created.**(Ezekiel28:12-13)**

Lucifer or Satan by description is much beautiful to Adam and Eve having a spirtual nature, so what is the reason of his envy?

My question is: **What are the traits and attributes of Adam and Eve that Satan envy so much, that motivates his action to destroy God's perfect creation of Adam and Eve?**

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer**

From scriptures Satan action to tempt Adam & Eve was ***motivated by ENVY***.

> "For God created man incorruptible, and to the image of his own likeness he made him. But by the envy of the devil, death came into the world. And they follow him that are of his side." (Book of Wisdom 2:23-25)

But why satan considered before as the Highest Angel with perfect beauty and full of wisdom should *ENVY* a man? Satan is only a "cherub" belonging to Choir of Cherubim and is second only in the sphere of Angel's Hierarchy the Choir of Seraphim being the highest.

But we can see from Ezekiel passage Lucifer aside from God's gift of perfect beauty and wisdom received another gift of "anointing" which allows him to pass the "fiery stones" the territory of Seraphim to guard the Holy Mountain of God, to the amazement of other angels and perhaps the cause of his head pluffing up.

So why a beautiful angel Lucifer which means a "bearer of light" would envy a created being of "body & soul" only?

**Answer**

The Fall of Lucifer has a great impact on his attributes, he lost two of the beautiful gifts:

> -Lucifer lost the anointing of God.
>
> -Lucifer lost the position of "bearer of Light".

Lucifer cast down to earth stripped of anointing and God's Light.,although the perfect angelic beauty and wisdom, Lucifer still possessed as Ezekiel28:12 describes the appearance of Lucifer now takes the name Satan.

So the envy of Satan rooted clearly when he saw the appearance of Adam & Eve they were clothe with God's Light ***"original holiness"*** was their clothing, the very clothing of Lucifer whom he lost after the fall.

So Lucifer/Satan was envy primarily of Adam & Eve "original holiness".

Although scriptures said, that still Satan can clothe or transformed himself as an angel of light it will now be a false light as it does not come from the God's holiness.

> "And no wonder: for Satan himself transformeth himself into an angel of light."
> (2 Corinthians 11:14)

Satan if he opted to appear to Adam & Eve as the angel of light will only be humiliated by virtue of God's Light "Original holiness" that Adam & Eve possessed his light is a false light and will only be inferior.

But, satan uses his one key advantage to Adam & Eve, satan has "perfect gift of  wisdom" while Adam & Eve only had beginning to acquire wisdom by their walk of obedience, so in this area satan has the advantage over them.

And, how does Satan strategized his attack motivated by ENVY? Satan want's Adam & Eve to be stripped of "orginal holiness" the same way he was stripped of God's Light as his superior clothing in Heavenly Realms and that is thru "PRIDE & DISOBEDIENCE".

In closing, we can see that Satan root of "ENVY" is because Adam & Eve has something the "original holiness" that he lost and satan by his ENVY seeks to destroy that image thru ***"PRIDE & DISOBEDIENCE***".

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Aquinas have an opinion:

God present the son of men and the lady in heaven for all angels knowledge that this is their king and queen in the future and they have to worship. Then Satan don't agree with this plan of God. He envy the son of men and the Lady. But he don't acting at that moment until God create Adam & Eve. Then Satan want to destroy God's Plan by deceive Adam & Eve.

Comment: Please add to your answer where in the Summa, or other works, Thomas Aquinas offered this opinion.  Welcome to Christianity.SE. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how an SE Q&A site is different from a discussion forum.  Supported answers are required here, or they will be removed.   Adding the source/support of this opinion from St Thomas is thus necessary.